# NullPointerException when Passing ArrayList through Intent using Parcelable

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I'm working on project and getting data from `WCF services` and make an `ArrayList`, everything is working fine. I'm successfully getting data from service. Now what I want is Passing that **ArrayList through Intent to another Activity**. Basically I know how to send **string and int**. values but I have no idea about how to pass an **ArrayList through Intent**. I have searched a lot and trying to send `ArrayList through Intent Using Parcelable`. but now Im recieving a **NullPointerException**. Can someone help sort out my problem. or let me know does I'm on doing correct or is there any alternate way to do this? Thanks in Advance

**`**HOW I TRIED**`**

**Quiz.java**

```
public class Quiz implements Parcelable{

private String id;
private String quiz_code;
private String question;
private String choice_A;
private String choice_B;
private String choice_C;
private String choice_D;
private String ans;
private String quiz_title;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getQuiz_code() {
    return quiz_code;
}
public void setQuiz_code(String quiz_code) {
    this.quiz_code = quiz_code;
}
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
public String getChoice_A() {
    return choice_A;
}
public void setChoice_A(String choice_A) {
    this.choice_A = choice_A;
}
public String getChoice_B() {
    return choice_B;
}
public void setChoice_B(String choice_B) {
    this.choice_B = choice_B;
}
public String getChoice_C() {
    return choice_C;
}
public void setChoice_C(String choice_C) {
    this.choice_C = choice_C;
}
public String getChoice_D() {
    return choice_D;
}
public void setChoice_D(String choice_D) {
    this.choice_D = choice_D;
}
public String getAns() {
    return ans;
}
public void setAns(String ans) {
    this.ans = ans;
}
public String getQuiz_title() {
    return quiz_title;
}
public void setQuiz_title(String quiz_title) {
    this.quiz_title = quiz_title;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.hashCode();
}

public Quiz(){

}

public Quiz(Parcel source) {
    id = source.readString();
    ans = source.readString();
    quiz_title = source.readString();
    choice_A = source.readString();
    choice_B = source.readString();
    choice_C = source.readString();
    choice_D = source.readString();
    quiz_code = source.readString();
    question = source.readString();

}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(ans);
    dest.writeString(quiz_title);
    dest.writeString(quiz_code);
    dest.writeString(question);
    dest.writeString(choice_A);
    dest.writeString(choice_B);
    dest.writeString(choice_C);
    dest.writeString(choice_D);

}

 public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
 = new Parcelable.Creator() {
 public Quiz createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
 return new Quiz(in);
 }

 public Quiz[] newArray(int size) {
 return new Quiz[size];
 }
};
}
```

sending ArrayList to anohter Activity through Intent:

**MainActivity:**

```
in = new Intent(GettingQuizTitleActivity.this,TestActivity.class);

            in.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", quizList);
            startActivity(in);
```

how i'm trying to receive an ArrayList

**SecondActivity:**

```
try{
    Intent intent = null;

    ArrayList<Quiz> test = (ArrayList<Quiz>) intent.<Quiz>getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");

    }
 catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: use intent=getIntent(); in second activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SecondActivity` By this line your `Intent` is `null`

```
Intent intent = null;
```

change this into

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

That too there is one more thing in your Parcelable..
The order in what what way you have written in your `writeToParcel()` method you need to follow the same in `Quiz(Parcel source)`

Comment: @MuneebAmjad accept it by clciking tick mark at the left side of the answer so it may helpful to others..

Answer (score 1):

In your second activity,

```
Intent intent = null;
```

should be:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

You are using `intent`(=null)  to get the list.

Answer (score 1):

change your code of secondActivity to this

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

ArrayList<Quiz> test = (ArrayList<Quiz>) intent.<Quiz>getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change here from

```
  Intent intent = null;
```

to

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
```

in your case your intent object is null. So you got problem.